# Create a LINQ expression for SELECT sentence

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have this LINQ query where the **"new"** sentence **creates an anonymous type**:

```
var query = from x in List
            select new {x.Field1, x.Field2};
```

How to build dynamically the LINQ Expression for:

```
select new {x.Field1, x.Field2};
```

**MORE CONTEXT:**

We have a List<Customer> where Customer has properties A, B, C, D, E, F, G.

We need to return only some properties sometimes:

First call returns:

```
 select new {x.A, x.B}
```

Second call returns:

```
 select new {x.C, x.D}
```

**The return is dynamic!** I have the names of the properties in string array.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate? The question is not very clear.

Comment: why do you tag EF, are your using it in this case?

Comment: Hi @YacoubMassad, I need to create the LINQ Expression, so I can to call the "Select" method like "Select(linqExpression)"

Comment: What input would you give to the expression building process? The field names?

Comment: Yes @YacoubMassad, the field names!

Comment: The problem here is with the type of the expression output parameter. Depending on the fields, you are going to generate a different output type every time. What would be the type of `query`?

Comment: something like this? `List.Select(x => new{x.Field1, x.Field2});`

Comment: @ABittersweetLife I need it dynamically

Comment: can you elaborate? the question is not clear.

Comment: More context @YacoubMassad

We have a List<Customer> where Customer has fields A, B, C, D, E, F, G.

We need to return only some fields sometimes:
First call: return new {x.A, x.B}
Second call: return new {x.C, x.D}

The return is dynamic!

Comment: Are you using something like AutoMapper by any chance?

Comment: Yes. But how are you going to consume the result? Do you expect that C# would infer the type of `query` and let you continue building on the query? Can you please show an expected usage example highlighting how you are going to use the output?

Comment: He can still use a return type of [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) type if he plans to return anonymous types that can change each time. Not exactly type safe but workable.

Comment: @YacoubMassad the result will be consumed by a jQuery Widget in JSON object... The jQuery knows how to use the dynamic JSON object.

Comment: So you really don't care about the type of the output, just how it looks when it is serialized into JSON, right?

Comment: Check out [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)

Comment: Yes! @YacoubMassad

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev... We have understand the Dynamic LINQ use, however, we need to fix the problem using a LINQ Expression in the Select extension method.

Comment: The problem is that anonymous types cannot be created dynamically at runtime. Dynamic LINQ is solving the problem by creating dynamic classes, which is not simple thing you can easily replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a CSV for the properties that you want to retrieve. You should be able to use this.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string,object> GetProperties(this object obj, string properties)
    {
        var propertyNames = properties.Split(',');
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var property in propertyNames)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(property);
            var value = prop.GetValue(obj);
            result.Add(property, value);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It stores the key value pair in a dictionary

The usage would be.

```
 var result = list.Select(p => p.GetProperties("Field1,Field2"));
 JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Serialize(Console.Out, result);
```